# C# ASP.NET application Regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

For a C#, ASP.NET application -
This should be simple, but I can't figure out this regular expression, I need a list of strings that a text box can *not* submit as a value, and I have to ignore the case.

Example -
  No matter the capitalization, I need my regular expression to *reject* the following strings -
      abc, def, ghi

I can't even get the regex to reject *one* of them. I tried the following manner -

> ```
> [RegularExpression(@"(\W|^)(?i)!ABC(?-i)(\W|$)", ErrorMessage = "REJECTED!")]
> public string Letters { get; set; }
> ```

That does not work! It seems to reject everything. Anyone know what it should look like?
How can I reject all of them?

Thanks for any help can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but give this a try (assuming I understand the problem correctly!)

```
^(?i)(?!(ABC|DEF|GHI)(?-i)).*$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore just strings, use this

```
^(?i)(?!.*(?:abc|def|ghi))
```

If you want to ignore words, use word boundaries around the pattern

```
^(?i)(?!.*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b)
```

Answer (score 2):

In standard regex syntax this would be `^(?!abc$)(?!def$).*`

Answer (score 2):

This will detect abc, def, and ghi

```
(?i)(abc|def|ghi)
```

enclose in `^` and `$` to only match those and nothing else (e.g. won't match *wxabcyz*)

```
^(?i)(abc|def|ghi)$
```

finally, if you want to match something like "This is some abc random text" and reject it, do this

```
(?i)\b(abc|def|ghi)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?!abc)|(?!def)|(?!ghi).)*$
```

Thats about it.

Btw I'd recommend you play around with something like the following resources you aren't 
already.
[regex pal](http://regexpal.com/)
and [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?i)(?!(ABC|DEF|GHI)(?-i)).*$
```